# OpenVPN: can't seem to route additional traffic through VLAN

Tags: routing, openvpn

Here's our network:

- we have various clients working from home with dynamic IP addresses, so they're impossible to create firewall rules for
- we have a number of servers at the same hosting provider
- that hosting provider offers a VLAN feature so the servers can reach each other internally
- we also have a *different* VPN that does accomplish this goal, but uses OpenVPN with a proprietary front-end, so I can't easily reverse-engineer how it does it

In this example, we have:

- `el-1`, which runs an OpenVPN server, providing the network `10.26/24` (and acting as a gateway at `10.26.0.1`). In the VLAN, it also has the address `192.168.50.51`.
- `master`, which is more heavily firewalled. In the VLAN, it has `192.168.50.41`.

I've already accomplished setting up an OpenVPN server, and those clients can connect and reach (otherwise firewalled) ports on `el-1` itself. Now I want those clients to somehow also access `master` through the same VPN, probably using the VLAN.

If I RDP into `el-1`, I can use the VLAN address of `192.168.50.41` to reach ports on `master` that aren't publicly open. So the VLAN *does* appear to work, and the firewall *doesn't* appear to be a problem at that stage.

Just for the sake of it, a client config:

```
client

dev tun

proto udp
remote (the server) 11194

resolv-retry infinite

nobind

persist-key
persist-tun

ca ca.crt
cert someUsername.crt
key someUsername.key

ns-cert-type server

cipher AES-256-CBC

comp-lzo

verb 3
```

Here's what the server config used to look like:

```
local 0.0.0.0

#we use a non-default port 11194
port 11194

proto udp

dev tun

client-config-dir ccd
ccd-exclusive

ca ..//easy-rsa//keys//ca.crt
cert ..//easy-rsa//keys//server.crt
key ..//easy-rsa//keys//server.key
dh ..//easy-rsa//keys//dh2048.pem

server 10.26.0.0 255.255.255.0

ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt

keepalive 10 60

cipher AES-256-CBC

comp-lzo

max-clients 20

persist-key
persist-tun

status ..//log//openvpn-status.log
verb 3
```

(I know `comp-lzo` and `ns-cert-type` are deprecated; that's a different matter.)

I then basically figured from the docs that `server` is a shorthand that may not accomplish this more complex scenario? So I broke that up as follows:

```
local 0.0.0.0

#we use a non-default port 11194
port 11194

proto udp

dev tun

client-config-dir ccd
ccd-exclusive

ca ..//easy-rsa//keys//ca.crt
cert ..//easy-rsa//keys//server.crt
key ..//easy-rsa//keys//server.key
dh ..//easy-rsa//keys//dh2048.pem

mode server
tls-server

ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt

keepalive 10 60

cipher AES-256-CBC

comp-lzo

max-clients 20

persist-key
persist-tun

status ..//log//openvpn-status.log
verb 3

# formerly the server directive
topology subnet
push "topology subnet"
ifconfig 10.26.0.1 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool 10.26.0.2 10.26.0.253
push "route-gateway 10.26.0.1"
```

I *think* that's supposed to be roughly equivalent, except now the topology is `subnet`, when it was `net30` before). I then added the following:

```
# VLAN
push "route 192.168.50.0 255.255.255.0 10.26.0.1 1"
```

And the result *looks* right on the client! From the client-side OpenVPN log:

```
2020-04-02 10:39:27.067370 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1585816767,ASSIGN_IP,,10.26.0.16,,,,
2020-04-02 10:39:27.067396 /sbin/ifconfig utun7 delete
                           ifconfig: ioctl (SIOCDIFADDR): Can't assign requested address
2020-04-02 10:39:27.072671 NOTE: Tried to delete pre-existing tun/tap instance -- No Problem if failure
2020-04-02 10:39:27.072721 /sbin/ifconfig utun7 10.26.0.16 10.26.0.16 netmask 255.255.255.0 mtu 1500 up
2020-04-02 10:39:27.076570 /sbin/route add -net 10.26.0.0 10.26.0.16 255.255.255.0
                           add net 10.26.0.0: gateway 10.26.0.16
2020-04-02 10:39:27.082300 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1585816767,ADD_ROUTES,,,,,,
2020-04-02 10:39:27.082345 /sbin/route add -net 192.168.50.0 10.26.0.1 255.255.255.0
                           add net 192.168.50.0: gateway 10.26.0.1
```

And the routes:

```
~> netstat -nr
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Netif Expire
default            192.168.2.234      UGSc           en0       
10.26/24           10.26.0.16         UGSc         utun7       
10.26.0.16         10.26.0.16         UH           utun7       
127                127.0.0.1          UCS            lo0       
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH             lo0       
169.254            link#4             UCS            en0      !
[..]
192.168.50         10.26.0.1          UGSc         utun7       
224.0.0/4          link#4             UmCS           en0      !
224.0.0.251        1:0:5e:0:0:fb      UHmLWI         en0       
255.255.255.255/32 link#4             UCS            en0      !
```

So that looks exactly correct, right? I should now be able to reach a port on `192.168.50.41` *through* the VPN at `10.26.0.1` (on `utun7`).

But it's filtered. I've temporarily disabled firewalls on both servers (which shouldn't be the reason); still filtered.

So,

- how do I verify that the correct route is used? `traceroute` just gets stuck:

```
    ~> traceroute -n 192.168.50.41
    traceroute to 192.168.50.41 (192.168.50.41), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
     1  * * *
     2  * * *
     3  * * *
```

- am I mostly correct about my config? Do I need bridging? Is there something very basic I'm missing?

Comment: (I tried bridging the two interfaces using Windows's built-in support, and that had… disastrous results for the IP stack, so I'd rather not try _that_ one again, unless someone is sure it's correct.)

Answer (score 0):

A few tips: `route -n` will return output similar to `netstat -nr` but will show route priorities (metric).

Does 10.26/24 mean 10.26.0.0/24 ? Then it seems to overlap with 10.26.0.16 and there is some route duplication.

Question:

> how do I verify that the correct route is used? traceroute just gets
>   stuck:

Use the ip route command to obtain the route for a given IP address eg:

```
ip route get 192.168.50.41
```

This alone should help you a lot with debugging.

I would check the OpenVPN configuration file carefully, I don't think you really need this:

```
ifconfig 10.26.0.1 255.255.255.0
```

If your server is indeed 10.26.0.1, the client should take care of that and add the route on the fly. But maybe I am missing something, I cannot picture your network setup 100% right now.

I suggest that you collect the output of `route -n` on the client *before* and *after* running OpenVPN, and compare results so you can see which routes were added from your configuration directives.

(disclaimer: the next section that follows is speculative, I invite you to double-check and research the idea)

Assuming that the VPN link otherwise works between client and server and that you have `iptables` on your server, you may need to add a rule so that clients are able to reach your local range 192.168.*

To give you an idea, here is a configuration I once did on a Raspberry PI to forward traffic between interfaces eth0 & wlan0:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

So maybe this type of rule could do the job and allow the VPN clients to transparently access the private range 192.168.*. You have to devise the exact rule depending on your network configuration but I don't know if this is going to be optimal from a security point of view, how your VLAN is set up etc. I lack some insight and I am not an iptables guru.

Hopefully someone else who is more experienced can chime in here. There must be more than one way to accomplish that.

I suppose that IP forwarding is already enabled on your server eg:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Note that we are just talking about IPv4 here but if your server is IPv6-capable and has IPv6 addresses configured you'll need to take care of that too.